# Color List In A Image

Tags: c#, image, gdi

I need most used 30 color list from  a image... I get it but there is alot of color tone's and i can't get main colors. for example picture has red color but i can't get red color.

What can i do?

```
Dictionary<string,int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\test.jpg");
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        var hexColor = c.R.ToString("X") + c.G.ToString("X") + c.B.ToString("X");

        if (d.ContainsKey(hexColor))
        {
            d[hexColor] = ++d[hexColor]; 
        }
        else
        {
            d.Add(hexColor, 1);
        }
    }
}


var items = (from pair in d
    orderby pair.Value descending
    select pair);
System.IO.StreamWriter file =
   new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\colors.html",false);

foreach (var v in items)
{
    file.WriteLine("<div style='width:50px;height:50px;float:left;margin-right:10px;background-color:#" + v.Key + "'>&nbsp;</div>");

}
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

RGB is composed of three primary colors: Red, Green, Blue. Each of them has a value in the range 0-255. Colors RGB (0,255,0), RGB (0,254,0), RGB (0,253,0), RGB (2,254,2) look the same, but in fact they are different. Perhaps you should add the tolerance range of colors.